# $I_n = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\cos t)^n \ dt$ converges to 0?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How one can prove that the sequence $\left ( I_n \right )$ defined as $$ I_n = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\cos t)^n  \ dt, $$ $n \in \{ 0,1,2,...\}$ converges to $0$?

Is easy to show, by the way, that the sequence is decreasing because, for $t  \in  (0, \pi/2)$, $$(\cos t)^{n+1}<(\cos t)^n \Rightarrow I_{n+1} < I_{n}, \ \forall n $$

Comment: The sequence is also bounded. 

$$ \left |I_n  \right | \leq \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left |(\cos t)^n  \right |  \ dt \leq \frac{\pi}{2} $$

So, by the monotone convergence Theorem, the sequence converges.

Comment: @Nosrati It's always positive between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: yes. and I think the proof is complete.

Answer (score 1):

With integation by parts one may show that
$$I_{n}=\dfrac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}$$
then from $I_0=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $I_1=1$, both odd and even terms go $0$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: Yes. But I was in need to prove the convergence without making any integration. That was the issue.

Comment: Well you've done by boundedness and decreasing property.

Comment: Yes. I think the demonstration is complete now.

Comment: my answer is extra life ;)

Comment: No doubt! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $\forall\varepsilon>0 \exists\delta>0: \cos x<1-\varepsilon$ on $(\delta,\pi/2]$ and $\delta$ decreases to $0$ when $\varepsilon$ tends to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation in the comments also makes Dominated Convergence work.

It remains to observe that on $(0, \frac \pi 2)$, the sequence converges pointwise to $0$. So pointwise a.e. convergence + dominated convergence implies the result.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

BTW the integrals can be done explicitly:
 $$ \int_0^{\pi/2} (\cos t)^n \; dt = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}\; \Gamma((n+1)/2)}{2 \;\Gamma(1+n/2)} \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}} \ \text{as}\ n \to \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a\in \Big(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\Big]$, let $f_{n}(t)=\cos(t)^{n}$ for all $t\in \Big[a,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\Big]$. If $\{f_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to the zero function, we can assure that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}f_{n}=\int_{a}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}=\int_{a}^\dfrac{\pi}{2}0dt=0$$

And the function does converge uniformly to $f(t)=0$, because we have that
$$ |f_{n}(t)|=|\cos(t)^{n}|\leq \cos(a)^{n} $$ for all $t$, since $\cos$ is a positive decreasing function in $\Big[a,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\Big]$. Therefore, due to the fact that $\cos(a)<1$, we have that $\lim \cos(a)^{n}=0$, which then implies uniform convergence to $f(t)=0$ in $\Big[a,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\Big]$, so the equality showed earlier is true for every choice of $a$.

This alone doesn't imply that the limit we're dealing with is $0$, but now it will be much easier to prove that it is.

Let $\varepsilon>0$, and WLOG I'll assume that $\varepsilon < \pi$. If we choose $a$ such that $0<a<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$, and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ which verifies $$n\geq N\implies \Bigg|\int_{a}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\cos(t)^{n}dt\Bigg|=\int_{a}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\cos(t)^{n}dt<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$$ we have that, given $n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq N$,

$$\Bigg|\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\cos(t)^{n}dt\Bigg|=\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\cos(t)^{n}dt=\int_{0}^{a}\cos(t)^{n}dt+\int_{a}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\cos(t)^{n}dt\leq \int_{0}^{a}1dt+\int_{a}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\cos(t)^{n}dt=a+\int_{a}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\cos(t)^{n}dt<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}+\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon$$

So we can conclude that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\cos(t)^{n}dt=0$$

Comment: Please replace every `\dfrac` by `\frac` (especially in the bounds of integrals, where you might even want to switch to `\pi/2`...).

Answer (score 0):

Let $I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos x)^ndx.$

For $x\in [0,\pi/2]$ we have $0\leq (\cos x)^{n+1}\leq (\cos x)^n\leq 1.$ So $0\leq I_{n+1}\leq I_n\leq \pi/2.$.... So $$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}I_n$$ exists and is not negative.

For $k\geq 1$  we have $$I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2k}(\cos x)^ndx +\int_{\pi/2k}^{\pi/2}(\cos x)^ndx\leq$$ $$\leq \int_0^{\pi/2k}(1)^ndx+\int_{\pi/2k}^{\pi/2}(\cos \pi/2k)^ndx=$$ $$=\pi/2k+(\pi/2-\pi/2k)(\cos \pi/2k)^n.$$ In this last expression, keeping  $k$ fixed and letting $n \to \infty,$ we have $(\cos \pi/2k)^n\to 0.$  Therefore $$L\leq \pi/2k +(\pi/2-\pi/2k)(0)=\pi /2k.$$  That is, $$\forall k\geq 1\;(0\leq L\leq  \pi/2k).$$ So $L=0.$